# HAML to HTML converter on Windows

Tags: gruntjs, haml, grunt-contrib-haml

Is there a haml to html converter for windows I see it on ubuntu we uses grunt. Ex. In the terminal grunt haml converts my code .haml to .php offline. Do windows have app or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [grunt-haml-php](https://github.com/alexluke/grunt-haml-php). But it doesn't work well on windows.
In order to make it run on windows, you have to make some hacks into it.

After installation is done, find node_moules/grunt-haml-php/tasks/haml.js file and we have to do some tweak like this.

```
...
var compileHaml = function(item, cb) {
  var args = ['-t', hamlTarget || 'php', item ];
  // change the above line to the following
  // var args = [path.join(__dirname, '../bin/haml'), '-t', hamlTarget || 'php', item ];
  ...

  var child = grunt.util.spawn({
    cmd: path.join(__dirname, '../bin/haml'),
    // change the above line to the following
    // cmd: 'php',
    args: args
  }, function(error, result, code) {
     cb(error, result.stdout);
  });
  ...
```

[grunt-haml-php](https://github.com/alexluke/grunt-haml-php) uses [MtHaml](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml), but looks like [MtHaml](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml) is still not stable. It lacks many features yet.

Hope this answer helps you what you're looking for.

Comment: @GoperLeoZosa, [slim](http://slim-lang.com) is getting more popular than HAML on Ruby on Rails, so I thought about implementing slim template engine into PHP.

Comment: There are several php libraries such as [maht0rz/jade](https://packagist.org/packages/maht0rz/jade), [kylekatarnls/jade-php](https://packagist.org/packages/kylekatarnls/jade-php), but these are all PHP ported versions of [Jade](https://jade-lang.com). So I decided to make a new php library that's similar to ruby's slim. I'll post a link to the repo once I finish the phase I.

Comment: Finally v0.0.1 released for [slimphp](https://packagist.org/packages/clthck/slimphp) and [grunt-slim-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-slim-php). It's very promising and I'm gonna add a number of slim features to them.

Comment: MtHaml is pretty stable (as in "no breaking change since months/years"), battle tested (as in "lots of people use it"), and well tested (as in "great code coverage"). Also, it can compile to Twig or PHP; compiling to Twig is a huge feature since you get all of Twig features for free.

Comment: @arnaud576875 I didn't mean to blame MtHaml actually. sorry about that. I just tried to say that slim is much slimer than haml. I tried to find out PHP version of slim template preprocessor but no luck. That's why I decided to make one.